# java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1

Tags: java

```
String separator=(char)92+"";

String parts[] = reader.split(separator);

for(String part:parts) {
    System.out.println(part);
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a question that is answerable?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions so you will be better prepared and able to ask a question that will be well received and more importantly **answerable**.

Comment: [When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. Click this comment to find out how to provide what we need to help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: what exactly is the character 92? what are you trying to do? just posting an Exception is **not** a question!

Answer (score 2):

This is how you declare a backslash in a regex pattern in Java. `\\\\`

```
String parts[] = reader.split("\\\\");
for (String part: parts) {
     System.out.println(part);
}
```

A regular backslash is written in a Java string as `\\` but when used as part of a pattern it needs to be escaped twice so `\\\\`.